# Making mobile device images for Windows Device emulator

Tags: windows-mobile, device-emulation

I have a mobile device.

How can I make an emulator image out of it?

To clarify: there is an environment set up on it that is needed for the program I am working on, and I wondered, if there is shortcut past setting it all on the emulated device from the ground.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to download emulators that plug into software packages like Visual Studio or eMbedded VC (haven't used that one in about 7+ years). These emulators come in the form of the SDK for the Mobile platform you are developing on. Mobile 6.5 SDK is [>> HERE <<](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17284).

Comment: I am well aware of them. However, that's not what i need. What i need is an emulator-image making tool that will allow me to emulate a mobile device with set-up environment (installed programs, files, registry etc) without having to set it up manually on blank emulator.